# Sending HTTP requests with different source IPs using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, python-requests, ipv6

I have a network interface that I assigned all IPv6 addresses from let's say the `2a00:3344:2000:1300::30/56` subnet.

I now want to issue `n` HTTP requests using `requests` and have the source IP of each request vary from within this `/56` subnet. Implementing this using a custom transport adapter like

```
import requests
from urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager


class SourceIPManager(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(
            num_pools=connections, maxsize=maxsize,
            block=block, source_address=('2a00:f48:2000:1300::30', 710))


s = requests.Session()
a = SourceIPManager()
s.mount('http://', a)

r = s.get('http://www.google.de')
```

does only work if I set `source_address` to `2a00:f48:2000:1300::30` (if this is the primary IP that `ip addr show dev eth0` shows). Specifying `2a00:f48:2000:1300::31` yields the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.google.de', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fbf23601a20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -9] Address family for hostname not supported',))
```

even though the interface is also assigned this IP address.

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve sending different requests with different source addresses using `requests`?

Comment: I seriously doubt you can have `4,722,366,482,869,645,213,696` addresses assigned to a single interface.You will not have enough RAM to do that, and, while IPv6 places no limit on the number of addresses assigned to an interface, the OS will only allow maybe a couple of dozen addresses for the interface. At `1,000,000` addresses assigned per second, it would take you over `149,642,763` years to assign that many addresses.

Comment: I think you are confused. If you assign `2a00:3344:2000:1300::30/56` to an interface, that is really assigning a single address. It is that IPv4 uses an explicit mask, e.g. `255.255.255.0`, where IPv6 only uses the mask length, e.g. `/56`. You should also only use `/64` networks for IPv6. An ISP can delegate a `/56` prefix, then you should use IPv6 prefix delegation to assign `/64` networks from that prefix.

Comment: @RonMaupin This is totally possible. Look at `AnyIP` in the linux kernel https://serverfault.com/questions/590038/adding-a-whole-ipv6-64-block-to-an-network-interface-on-debian

Comment: @Sirens, there is a big difference between assigning a huge number of addresses to an interface and routing traffic for a network to an interface.. For example, your router will happily route traffic for the entire Internet from your network, but it will not terminate and process the traffic the way TCP requires for HTTP requests.